# Want to write a query on queried result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
.get(function(req, res){
    Recipt.find({'User':req.params.name})
          .sort('-allRecipt.recipt_Number') 
          .limit(1)
          .select('allRecipt')
          .exec(function(err, doc){
              if(err) res.send(err);
              console.log(doc);
    });
});
```

I have a code like this which sort out the document from mongoose with maximum value of recipt_Number which is a field of array allRecipt . But all recipt further contains a number of recipt_Number records and i want to fetch the one with maximum value.

Comment: could you post an example doc? or the relevant bits from it at least...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your collection has the following documents:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("550999a3c89ce9e17ea01845"),
    "user" : "Chris",
    "allRecipt" : [ 
        {
            "update_time" : NumberLong(1426690563),
            "recipt_Number" : NumberLong(4)
        }
    ]
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("550999a3c89ce9e17ea01846"),
    "user" : "Chris",
    "allRecipt" : [ 
        {
            "update_time" : NumberLong(1426690563),
            "recipt_Number" : NumberLong(8)
        }
    ]
}
```

You could try following aggregation set, it returns what you need:

```
Recipt.aggregate([
    {$match: {user: req.params.name}},
    {$unwind: '$allRecipt'},
    {$project:{ "allRecipt.recipt_Number": 1 }},
    {$sort:{ "allRecipt.recipt_Number": -1 }},
    {$limit: 1}    
], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(result);
});
```

Returns:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("550999a3c89ce9e17ea01846"),
            "allRecipt" : {
                "recipt_Number" : NumberLong(8)
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: thnx..it get me what i wanted